# Adding Rows to a Pandas Dataframe Recursively

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple rows in a Pandas dataframe. depending on the data in the rows, I want to add additional rows and was looking at the most efficient way to do so . Here is an example of just two rows of the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
end_date="2020-12-31"
df= pd.DataFrame({'type':['Asset','Liability'],'Amount':\
[10,-5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-01-23'],\
'Original Maturity':[365,730]})
```

The Original Maturity refers to the number of days for the new trade. Thus when an Asset matures, it gets replicated with a new trade with the same original maturity and a maturity date that is 365 days after the original asset matures.

I want to duplicate the rows depending upon the end date of 2020-12-31 and the Original Maturity column. The Maturity column for each new row needs to reflect the revised Maturity. For the dataset above, I would expect to see the following output:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'type':\
['Asset','Liability','Asset','Asset','Liability']\
,'Amount':[10,-5,10,10,-5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22',\
'2018-01-23','2019-01-22','2020-01-22','2020-01-23'],\
'Original Maturity':[365,730,365,365,730]})
df
```

In this case, the "type" Asset will be replicated twice while the liability will be replicated just once due to the Original Maturity.

Was curious about the most efficient way to code this logic up.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I've misunderstood your question at a fundamental level. I will retract my answer for now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @coldspeed using your initial code, I worked out a solution. Took forever, but got there in the end !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to work out an answer based on initial code by @coldspeed

```
df['Maturity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Maturity Date'], errors='coerce')

i = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
j = df['Maturity Date'] 
d=round(((i-j).dt.days)/(df['Original Maturity']).clip(0))
e = pd.to_numeric(d).round(1).astype(int) +1


idx = df.index.repeat(e)


df = df.reindex(index=idx)


df['Maturity Date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()*df['Original Maturity'], unit='D')
df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Maturity Date')


df
```